# Можно ли получить имя метода класса typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

подскажите, пожалуйста. У меня есть объект некого типа. Я хочу разбить его на два других, в одном из которых будет одно поле из первоначального, а в другом будут все остальные. Как это делается с использованием типов?

```
export class Dto {
val1: string;
val2: number;
id: number;
}
export type someDtoWithoutId = Omit<Dto, 'id'>;
export type id = Pick<Dto, 'id'>;
```

Вот предположим я сделал два типа для этого добра. Не пойму как теперь этим воспользоваться? Как привести тип объекта A: Dto в объект B: SomeDtoWithoutId. Понятное дело можно переназначить все поля данного объекта но может есть какой-то более элегантный способ воспользоваться этими созданными типами? Есть ли удобный механизм приведения одного типа в другой? Или они только для описания?

Comment: const newDto = <LessonDto>OldDto;
const id = <DtoId>dto;
Пробовал вот такую конструкцию для приведения типа, в это не дало желаемого эффекта

Comment: что значит "воспользоваться созданными типами"? Вы хотите, чтобы у вас лишние поля удалялись, когда вы Dto к Id приводите?

Comment: Ну если коротко, то да, просто подумал что может есть для этого какой-то механизм для этого

Comment: Нет, TS не так работает. Но вы можете ф-цию написать, которая из объектов Dot будет создавать объект id `const idExtractor = ({id}: Dto): id => ({ id })`. p.s. названия типов и интерфейсов надо начинать с заглавной буквы

Comment: Спасибо преогромное, попробую сделать так